# Can components of different Adobe Creative Suites be installed alongside each other?

Tags: installation, adobe-cs5, software-activation

Last year I purchased [Adobe Design Standard](http://www.adobe.com/products/creativesuite/designstandard/) (which is primarily Photoshop, Illustrator, and InDesign) on a student license.

This year, I have a need for DreamWeaver, as well, and possibly other components of [Web Premium](http://www.adobe.com/education/products/creativesuite/web/). I'm considering buying a student license for Web Premium as well, but I will still need to use InDesign from the Design Standard package.

Is it possible to install Web Premium, and then install InDesign alone from a different Creative Suite, or will the two Suites conflict with (or refuse to install on top of) each other?

Answer (score 2):

It won't hurt anything: they'll coexist just fine. I've done it in the past with CS3 Design Std and Web Std.

You might want to look at Design Premium in the future though if you need web support too as it comes with Dreamweaver and Flash along with the design apps. Web Premium doesn't include InDesign.

In fact, you may be able to buy an upgrade from Design Standard to Design Premium.  Unless you really need Contribute or Flash Builder (Design Prem includes Flash Pro and Flash Catalyst), this would be the ideal way to go. I know the SKUs exist for corporate licensing, but I'm not sure about academic.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'd been comparing Design Premium with Web Premium, and, since I already *have* InDesign via Design Standard, figured I might as well take the package that includes Flash Builder. But upgrading Design Standard to Design Premium would be ideal from a cost perspective! I'll look into it.

Comment: Further to the Standard -> Premium upgrade idea: it appears there's no upgrade pricing through the Education store, and the retail upgrade from Standard to Premium is $399 USD... Might as well just buy one of the Education packages. :)

Comment: I can't imagine that the Retail EULA allows upgrades from Academic licenses anyway, for whatever that's worth.  :-)

Comment: (I'm sure you're right. I suspect we'll be using CS5.5 for *quite a while...* :)